# How to correctly implement throw exception when other thread try to access synchronised block?

Tags: java, multithreading

## Introduction

I got `verySlowMethod`.

- This method should be will be run few times per day.
  There is no requirements how often. But if this method is
  called immediately after previous call it means that something goes wrong.
  For this example we will assume that immediately means one minute period.
- This method should never be run in parallel.

## What I want to achieve

I want to rise `MyException` when any thread try to run
`verySlowMethod` in parallel.
If two threads compete for the lock one should get it and one should end up with exception.

## What I implemented

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock()

void verySlowMethod(String thisOperationId) {
   requireNonNull(thisOperationId);

   if (lock.isLocked()) throw new MyException();

   

   synchronized (lock) {
        // business operations here
           ...
```

## Problem

With current impl there is still possibility
that two threads will saw that lock is free
and run this method one after another without exception.

## Question

How I can do this correctly?

Comment: Have you tried Lock.tryLock() ? or had a look in the package java.util.concurrent.locks more generally ? It's much more flexible than synchronized blocks.

Comment: Consider scheduling it using a scheduling tool, so it's not ever called concurrently. if you scale out horizontally, in-machine checks like you're asking for won't work so you'll have to use a distributed tool anyway.

Comment: QuentinC this is what I looked for. I will accept this as answer.

Comment: Side note: Never use `synchronized` on a `Lock` object; use the methods of `Lock` instead.

Comment: Can you just cache the most recent result, and return the cached result if it is less than a minute old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments under question I decided to use:

[Lock.tryLock()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)

which solves all problems.

### Example:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

void verySlowMethod(String thisOperationId) {
    if (lock.tryLock()) {
            try {
                requireNonNull(thisOperationId);
                // ...slow operations here
              } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        } else {
            throw new OperationAlreadyInProgressException();
        }
    }
```